# Tag question with indirect tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Every once in a while I find myself in the situation where I don't know if I should include a tag when using a framework. For example: I use several frameworks like the Spring framework. These frameworks may have a solution for my problem. However the frameworks do not directly affect the question nor a solution but may offer an answer.

Should I include a framework tag like "Spring" when using "Spring" and it may offer an answer or should I name the framework in the question and leave out the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is asking how to do something, and you are interested in a solution using a framework, when it is available, or a generic solution when there isn't a specific solution using the framework, I would use both the tag for the framework, and the language. IMO, this is preferable than asking two questions where one is about using the framework, and one is about the language.

To make an example, if I wanted to know which function I should use in my code, and I am not sure if Drupal has the function I am looking for, I would tag the question with [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal), and [php](/questions/tagged/php). If I want to know if Drupal has a function that I could use, I would tag the question with [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal). In the latter example, if I tag the question also with [php](/questions/tagged/php), I would probably get answers about PHP functions, or plain PHP code to use when I am interested in one or more Drupal functions. Who knows PHP could not know Drupal has specific functions, including those functions that extend a PHP function. (See the functions listed in [this page](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/drupal_array), as example.)

Comment: Thanks, the use cases are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should include any tags possible so that the person whom knows most in the pacific tag can help you ASAP which can help you get a faster and more accurate answer. It doesn't hurt to add it anyways right? Hope this helped!

Comment: No, don't just add every single applicable tag.  Tags are *not* keywords.  Pick tags with explicit intent and care, don't just throw everything in there.